# Adding a background like light box to menu

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to add a lightbox effect to my menu.
I have tried this but the whole page fades out including the menu.

```
$('.nav').hover(function() {
       $('body').not(document.getElementById( "topnav" )).addClass('overlay');
    },
    function() {
        $('body').removeClass('overlay');
    });


.overlay {
 position:'fixed';
 width: '100%';
 height : '100%';
 opacity : 0.6;
 background: '#000';
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather then targeting body - target children (or, **better, one specified child** -> main container, or content div, or better, just make one hidden div and show/hide it).

Also, your nav should be at the top of the stack, hence - its z-index should be highest. And, btw, since nav is child of body, increasing its z-index would not work, if you use body as target.

Something like this:

```js
$('.nav').hover(function() {
       $('.overlay').show();
    },
    function() {
        $('.overlay').hide();
    });
```

```css
.overlay {
 position:fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height : 100%;
 opacity : 0.6;
 background: #000;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
z-index:5;
  display:none;
}
.nav {
  background:red;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
z-index:9;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='nav'>
11111
</div>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```